# Changing Colors of Document

Tags: color

I have a many pdf documents written in standard LaTeX format. I was interested, is it possible to make my pages be **black** but my text be **white**? In other words, invert black/white, I am curious how nice it would look like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Colors can be set via package `color`. It is important to set the color to white in the *preamble*. Then package `color` uses this color as `\normalcolor`. LaTeX uses this color at various places. For example, it resets the color in header and footers to make them independent from the color that is active at the time the output routine is called.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{color}
\pagecolor{black}
\color{white}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

> [image: Page 1]  [image: Page 2]  [image: Page 3]

## Switching colors

Also the colors can be switched on a page level. Some pages can be put as white on black and others as black on white.

The page color can be turned off by `\nopagecolor`. This is only supported by few drivers (`pdftex.def`, `dvips.def`). For other drivers, `\pagecolor{white}` can be used.

The `\normalcolor` is more tricky, the following example hacks into the internals to define `\whiteonblack` and `\blackonwhite`, which also changes the `\normalcolor` accordingly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{color}

\makeatletter
\let\default@color@black\current@color
\newcommand*{\blackonwhite}{%
  \newpage
  \let\default@color\default@color@black
  \normalcolor
  \@ifundefined{no@page@color}{%
    \pagecolor{white}%
  }{%
    \nopagecolor
  }%
}
\color{white}
\let\default@color@white\current@color
\newcommand*{\whiteonblack}{%
  \newpage
  \let\default@color\default@color@white
  \normalcolor
  \pagecolor{black}%
}
\pagecolor{black}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\blackonwhite \blinddocument
\whiteonblack \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, but my page numbering disappears! (Presummably stays as black).

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki No, as you can see, the page numbers are correctly set in white. You have to move `\color{white}` to the preamble. See my updated answer with a little more explanation.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek `\pagecolor` command is from `color` package?

Comment: @juanuni Yes, `\pagecolor` is defined in package `color`. It is supported in drivers `pdftex.def`, `dvips.def`, `dvipdfmx.def`, for example.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek thanks. Your solution makes all pages in color. There are something like `\thispagecolor`? (for a specific page)

Comment: @juanuni No, but you can use `\pagecolor` again after the changed page. Some drivers (`pdftex.def`) also supports `\nopagecolor`.

Comment: @juanuni The [pagecolor package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pagecolor) provides `\thepagecolor`, which does not "change the color of this page", but returns the color of this page. (While you did not ask for this, I add this comment to prevent confusion of those two commands.)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,lipsum}
\pagecolor{black}
\color{white}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2-4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Two problems. (i) I get a bunch of random words in the beginning. (ii) My page numbering disappears!

Comment: `\color{white}` should be moved before `\begin{document}`. Then this color becomes the `\normalcolor` instead of the default black and the page number will reappear as white on black.

Comment: @Heiko Oberdiek Thank you for pointing out. Edited my answer for page number colour in white.